# Probability Density Function - Find c

Tags: probability

I have a continuous random variable X that has a probability density function of $f(x) = c  e^{-|x-1|}$ for all x between negative $-\infty$ and $\infty$.

How could I go about finding the value for c, and what should it be?

Thanks!

Comment: You know that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx = 1$, so evaluate the integral and figure out what value of $c$ will make that true.

Answer (score 1):

$c$ is determined by the equation

$$c \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, e^{-|x-1|} = 1$$

Now,

$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, e^{-|x-1|} &= \int_{-\infty}^1 dx \, e^{(x-1)} + \int_1^{\infty} dx \, e^{-(x-1)}\\ &= 2 \int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{-x}\\ &= 2\end{align}$$

Thus, $c=1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: In order for $f$ to be a probability density function, you must have

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx=1\;,$$

so it’s just a matter of evaluating

$$c\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-|x-1|}\,dx\;,$$

setting it to $1$, and solving for $c$. The integral is straightforward after you split it into two integrals to account for the fact that

$$|x-1|=\begin{cases}
x-1,&\text{if }x\ge 1\\
1-x,&\text{if }x<1\;.
\end{cases}$$